# How to distinguish between table elements with identical names? Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, html-table

I need to get to the second table's element. However since the web page contains two tables, I always end up getting an element from the first table.
Here is the code:

```
driver.get("http:.............");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[1]/td[2]")).getText();
        System.out.println(el);
```

//I need to get the following value: $0.00564000. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Try: `String el = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[1]/td[2]")).get(1).getText();`

Comment: why don't you use ids instead?

Comment: @acdcjunior thanks, I tried it, but I got `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @Franz Ebner do you mean findElement(By.id...)? There are no ids on that web page for that table elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String el = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[2]/td[2]")).get(1).getText();
```